# Why are my primary and secondary DocumentDB keys not showing in the Azure portal?

Tags: azure, primary-key, azure-cosmosdb

I just created a new DocumentDB instance. When I go to the "Keys" area on the new Azure portal, I don't see a primary key or secondary key. My URI is listed. I tried use the regenerate feature hoping that would create the keys, but no luck. Anyone else have this problem? How would I report this to Msft without a technical support subscription?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The account can take several minutes to provision, during which time the keys will not be available (since the account has finished creating).  If, in the portal, you choose to Browse | DocumentDB accounts, you will see the status (creating, updating, online).  Once your account is in an online state, the keys will be available.  Can you ensure that the account is indeed in an online state and, if so, refresh your browser and see if the keys are available?

Comment: Bingo! Even though it had been a few hours, it looks like the browser was cached and it took a full restart to get them listed. Thanks!